# How can I post username data from one table automatically in another? VueJs + Laravel + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vue.js

I have a users table which displays the registered users in the users section from the database(sql) of my Laravel Vue app. I now have an Employees table which has a form for business information. I need to have one of the fields that exists in the database called empuser auto populated with the name from the user table when posting the empleado form. when I submit the form, I get a SQL error saying that I have no default value for the empuser field.
I am using phpmyadmin with SQL in local development. In my case, it isn't that sql isn't working, it is that I am unsure how to make the relationships in this type of environment, ie, VueJs and Laravel. The error I am getting is `"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'empuser' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into` empleados `(`emprfc`,`... etc.
Database Migration:
User_table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('type')->default('user');
            $table->mediumText('bio')->nullable();
            $table->string('photo')->default('profile.png');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Employee table

```
   public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('empleados', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
$table->string('emprfc', 20)->unique();
$table->string('empnombre', 75);
$table->string('empcalle', 100)->nullable();
$table->string('empcolonia', 50)->nullable();
$table->string('empciudad', 50);
$table->string('empestado', 50);
$table->string('empcpostal', 5);
$table->string('emppais', 25);
$table->string('empstatus', 1)->default('1');
$table->bigInteger('empuser');
$table->bigInteger('empregby');
$table->timestamps();
$table->index('empciudad');
$table->index('empestado');
$table->index('empcpostal');
$table->index('emppais');
$table->index('empuser');
$table->index('empregby');
        });
    }
```

Users.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row pt-3">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="card-title">Tablero de Usuarios</h3>

            <div class="card-tools">
              <!-- <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addNew"> -->
              <button class="btn btn-success" @click="newModal">
                <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> Añadir Nuevo
                Usuario
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.card-header -->
          <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0">
            <table class="table table-hover text-nowrap">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Nombre</th>
                  <th>Correo</th>
                  <th>Rol</th>
                  <th>Registrado</th>
                  <th>Modificar</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
                  <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
                  <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
                  <td>{{ user.type | upText }}</td>
                  <td>{{ user.created_at | myDate }}</td>
                  <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" @click="editModal(user)">
                      <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#" @click="deleteUser(user.id)">
                      <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <!-- /.card-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <form @submit.prevent="editmode ? updateUser() : createUser()">
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div
        class="modal fade"
        id="addNew"
        tabindex="-1"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 v-show="!editmode" class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Añadir Nuevo</h5>
              <h5
                v-show="editmode"
                class="modal-title"
                id="exampleModalLabel"
              >Actualizar datos de Usuario</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input
                  v-model="form.name"
                  type="text"
                  name="name"
                  placeholder="Nombre de Usuario"
                  class="form-control"
                  :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has('name')
                                    }"
                />
                <has-error :form="form" field="name"></has-error>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <input
                  v-model="form.email"
                  type="email"
                  name="name"
                  placeholder="Correo Electrónico"
                  class="form-control"
                  :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has('email')
                                    }"
                />
                <has-error :form="form" field="email"></has-error>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <input
                  v-model="form.bio"
                  type="text"
                  name="bio"
                  placeholder="Bio breve de Usuario (Opcional)"
                  class="form-control"
                  :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has('bio')
                                    }"
                />
                <has-error :form="form" field="name"></has-error>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <select
                  id="type"
                  v-model="form.type"
                  name="type"
                  class="form-control"
                  :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has('type')
                                    }"
                >
                  <option value>Eliges el Rol de Usuario</option>
                  <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                  <option value="user">Usuario Estándar</option>
                  <option value="author">Autor</option>
                </select>
                <has-error :form="form" field="name"></has-error>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input
                  v-model="form.password"
                  type="password"
                  name="password"
                  placeholder="Contraseña"
                  class="form-control"
                  :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has(
                                            'password'
                                        )
                                    }"
                />
                <has-error :form="form" field="password"></has-error>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
              <button v-show="editmode" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Actualizar</button>
              <button v-show="!editmode" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Crear</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      updateUser() {
        this.$Progress.start();
        this.form
          .put("api/user/" + this.form.id)
          .then(() => {
            // successfull
            $("#addNew").modal("hide");
            swal.fire("Actualizó", "Datos del usuario actualizados", "success");
            this.$Progress.finish();
            Fire.$emit("AfterCreate");
          })
          .catch(() => {
            // Unsuccessfull
            this.$Progress.fail();
          });
      },
      editmode: true,
      users: {},
      form: new Form({
        id: "",
        name: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        type: "",
        bio: "",
        photo: "",
      }),
    };
  },
  methods: {
    editModal(user) {
      this.editmode = true;
      this.form.reset();
      $("#addNew").modal("show");
      this.form.fill(user);
    },
    newModal() {
      this.editmode = false;
      this.form.reset();
      $("#addNew").modal("show");
    },
    deleteUser(id) {
      swal
        .fire({
          title: "¿Estas seguro?",
          text: "¡No podrás revertir esto!",
          icon: "warning",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
          cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
          confirmButtonText: "¡Sí, Bórralo!",
        })
        .then((result) => {
          // Send Request to the server

          this.form
            .delete("api/user/" + id)
            .then(() => {
              if (result.value) {
                swal.fire(
                  "Borrado!",
                  "El usuario ha sido eliminado.",
                  "success"
                );
                Fire.$emit("AfterCreate");
              }
            })
            .catch(() => {
              swal("¡Fallo!", "Algo salió mal", "warning");
            });
        });
    },
    loadUsers() {
      axios.get("api/user").then(({ data }) => (this.users = data.data));
    },
    createUser() {
      this.$Progress.start();
      this.form
        .post("api/user")
        .then(() => {
          Fire.$emit("AfterCreate");
          $("#addNew").modal("hide");

          toast.fire({
            icon: "success",
            title: "Usuario creado con éxito",
          });
          this.$Progress.finish();
        })
        .catch(() => {
          this.$Progress.fail();
          toast.fire({
            icon: "error",
            title: "Usuario no fue creado.",
          });
        });
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.loadUsers();
    Fire.$on("AfterCreate", () => {
      this.loadUsers();
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

UserController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;  
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return User::latest()->paginate(10);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:191',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:8'
        ]);
        return User::create([
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'type' => $request['type'],
            'bio' => $request['bio'],
            'photo' => $request['photo'],
            'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
        ]);
    }
 
    public function empleado()
    {
        return auth('api')->user();
    }

    public function updateProfile(Request $request)
    {
        $user =  auth('api')->user();

        if($request->photo) {
           $name = time().'.' . explode('/', explode(':', substr($request->photo, 0, strpos ($request->photo, ';')))[1])[1]; 
           \Image::make($request->photo)->save(public_path('img/profile/').$name);
        }
        // return ['message' => 'Éxito'];
    }

    public function profile()
    {
        return auth('api')->user();
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:191',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,email,'.$user->id,
            'password' => 'sometimes|min:8'
        ]);

        $user->update($request->all());
        return ['message' => 'Actualizó los datos del usuario.'];
    }
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        // Delete the user
        $user->delete();

        return ['message' => 'Usuario Eliminado'];
    }
}
```

User.php

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use  HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'bio', 'photo', 'type'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Empleado.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row pt-3">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="card-title">Tablero de Emmpleados</h3>
            <div class="card-tools">
              <!-- <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addNew"> -->
              <button class="btn btn-success" @click="newModal">
                <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> Añadir Nuevo
                Empleado
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.card-header -->
          <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0">
            <table class="table table-hover text-nowrap">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>RFC</th>
                  <th>Nombre</th>
                  <th>Calle</th>
                  <th>Colonia</th>
                  <th>Ciudad</th>
                  <th>Estado</th>
                  <th>Código Postal</th>
                  <th>País</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr v-for="empleado in empleados" :key="empleado.id">
                  <td>{{ empleado.emprfc }}</td>
                  <td>{{ empleado.empnombre }}</td>
                  <td>{{ empleado.empcalle }}</td>
                  <td>{{ empleado.empcolonia }}</td>
                  <td>{{ empleado.empestado }}</td>
                  <td>{{ empleado.empcpostal }}</td>
                  <td>{{ empleado.pais }}</td>
                  <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" @click="editModal(empleado)">
                      <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#" @click="deleteEmpleado(empleado.id)">
                      <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <!-- /.card-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <form @submit.prevent="editmode ? updateEmpleado() : createEmpleado()">
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div
        class="modal fade"
        id="addNew"
        tabindex="-1"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 v-show="!editmode" class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Añadir Nuevo</h5>
              <h5
                v-show="editmode"
                class="modal-title"
                id="exampleModalLabel"
              >Actualizar datos de Empleado</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input
                  v-model="form.emprfc"
                  type="text"
                  name="emprfc"
                  placeholder="RFC"
                  class="form-control"
                  :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has('emprfc')
                                    }"
                />
                <has-error :form="form" field="emprfc"></has-error>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <input
                  v-model="form.empnombre"
                  type="text"
                  name="empnombre"
                  placeholder="Nombre"
                  class="form-control"
                  :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has('empnombre')
                                    }"
                />
                <has-error :form="form" field="empnombre"></has-error>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <input
                  v-model="form.empcalle"
                  type="text"
                  name="empcalle"
                  placeholder="Calle"
                  class="form-control"
                  :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has('empcalle')
                                    }"
                />
                <has-error :form="form" field="empcalle"></has-error>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <input
                  v-model="form.empcolonia"
                  type="text"
                  name="empcolonia"
                  placeholder="Colonia"
                  class="form-control"
                  :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has(
                                            'empcolonia'
                                        )
                                    }"
                />
                <has-error :form="form" field="empcolonia"></has-error>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <input
                  v-model="form.empciudad"
                  type="text"
                  name="empciudad"
                  placeholder="Ciudad"
                  class="form-control"
                  :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has(
                                            'empciudad'
                                        )
                                    }"
                />
                <has-error :form="form" field="empciudad"></has-error>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <input
                  v-model="form.empestado"
                  type="text"
                  name="empestado"
                  placeholder="Estado"
                  class="form-control"
                  :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has(
                                            'empestado'
                                        )
                                    }"
                />
                <has-error :form="form" field="empestado"></has-error>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <input
                  v-model="form.empcpostal"
                  type="text"
                  name="empcpostal"
                  placeholder="Código Postal"
                  class="form-control"
                  :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has(
                                            'empcpostal'
                                        )
                                    }"
                />
                <has-error :form="form" field="empcpostal"></has-error>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <input
                  v-model="form.emppais"
                  type="text"
                  name="emppais"
                  placeholder="País"
                  class="form-control"
                  :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has(
                                            'emppais'
                                        )
                                    }"
                />
                <has-error :form="form" field="emppais"></has-error>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
              <button v-show="editmode" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Actualizar</button>
              <button v-show="!editmode" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Crear</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      updateEmpleado() {
        this.$Progress.start();
        this.form
          .put("api/empleado/" + this.form.id)
          .then(() => {
            // successfull
            $("#addNew").modal("hide");
            swal.fire("Actualizó", "Datos del usuario actualizados", "success");
            this.$Progress.finish();
            Fire.$emit("AfterCreate");
          })
          .catch(() => {
            // Unsuccessfull
            this.$Progress.fail();
          });
      },
      editmode: true,
      empleados: {},
      form: new Form({
        id: "",
        emprfc: "",
        empnombre: "",
        empcalle: "",
        empcolonia: "",
        empciudad: "",
        empestado: "",
        empcpostal: "",
        emppais: "",
      }),
    };
  },
  methods: {
    editModal(empleado) {
      this.editmode = true;
      this.form.reset();
      $("#addNew").modal("show");
      this.form.fill(empleado);
    },
    newModal() {
      this.editmode = false;
      this.form.reset();
      $("#addNew").modal("show");
    },
    deleteEmpleado(id) {
      swal
        .fire({
          title: "¿Estas seguro?",
          text: "¡No podrás revertir esto!",
          icon: "warning",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
          cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
          confirmButtonText: "¡Sí, Bórralo!",
        })
        .then((result) => {
          // Send Request to the server

          this.form
            .delete("api/empleado/" + id)
            .then(() => {
              if (result.value) {
                swal.fire(
                  "Borrado!",
                  "El empleado ha sido eliminado.",
                  "success"
                );
                Fire.$emit("AfterCreate");
              }
            })
            .catch(() => {
              swal("¡Fallo!", "Algo salió mal", "warning");
            });
        });
    },
    loadEmpleados() {
      axios
        .get("api/empleado")
        .then(({ data }) => (this.empleados = data.data));
    },
    createEmpleado() {
      this.$Progress.start();
      this.form
        .post("api/empleado")
        .then(() => {
          Fire.$emit("AfterCreate");
          $("#addNew").modal("hide");
          toast.fire({
            icon: "success",
            title: "Empleado creado con éxito",
          });
          this.$Progress.finish();
        })
        .catch(() => {
          this.$Progress.fail();
          toast.fire({
            icon: "error",
            title: "Empleado no fue creado.",
          });
        });
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.loadEmpleados();
    Fire.$on("AfterCreate", () => {
      this.loadEmpleados();
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

EmpleadoController.php

```
<?php  
namespace App;  
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;    
class Empleado extends Authenticatable
{
    use  HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'emprfc', 'empnombre', 'empcalle', 'empcolonia', 'empciudad', 'empestado', 'empcpostal', 'emppais'
    ];    
    protected $hidden = [
        //
    ];    
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Empleado.php

```
<?php    
namespace App;    
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;    
class Empleado extends Authenticatable
{
    use  HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
    protected $fillable = [
        'emprfc', 'empnombre', 'empcalle', 'empcolonia', 'empciudad', 'empestado', 'empcpostal', 'emppais'
    ];   

    protected $hidden = [
        //
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

[image: Image of network data tab showing me as user.]
Here you can see that my user name is being returned correctly.

[image: Here is the Employee data entry form for the user (me in this case).]
Here I have the form to add employee data.

[image: Image of network error]
In this image, you can see the type of error I am receiving.

If I am missing any code, please let me know so I can edit my query. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Make sure `empuser` is present in the arguments when you call `User::create()`. It is not nullable so it must have a value as all non-nullable fields must have

Comment: You show us the *Empleado form* and then you gave us the *User methods*, but you should gave us the **Empleado Controller**, apparently, just as the comment on above, in your store method the field `empuser` isn't getting a value

Comment: I will employ the suggestions and let you both know of the results. Thank you.